# C - trouble with sscanf

Tags: c, locale, scanf

I have problem with sscanf and parsing floats. The problem is I'm trying to load floating point data from text file, but it behaves oddly on different locales on Linux. It seems to depend on OS decimal point setting (, or .), where in file I load it is always decimal point.

So code is like:

```
sscanf(line[i],"%f %f %f %f %f",&floatbuffer[0],&floatbuffer[1], &floatbuffer[2], &floatbuffer[3], &floatbuffer[4]);
```

but it doesn't work on locales that use comma (,) as decimal point, for example pl_PL. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried:

```
#include <locale.h>

setlocale(LC_NUMERIC,"C");
```

Comment: Then you may be facing an different problem, since I tested this to work with both `printf()` and `sscanf()`. Maybe try locale `"POSIX"`, or another locale which is installed (check installed locales by running `locale -a`)

Answer (score 1):

You can read/write binary data.
But be careful with portability.